# How to properly export fbx. file with animations to Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, export, unity

I developed a model for a boss in my group project.

The main body has its own armature, with two robotic tentacle arms paired to its shoulder bones. Along with these tentacles are two IK targets. Animations have been keyframed for the bones in the tentacles, the claws, the IK Targets, and the main body itself.

In Blender, they work fine besides some snapping due to the IK on the tentacles. But when trying to export all of this to Unity, no matter what I select, only one of the tentacles (right if facing front) will move. I've been able to export the body without the tentacles and the animations work fine. Is there a step I'm missing or some way to streamline this process?

I've included some images and will also link the blend file as well. Thank you for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5wNgx50j" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5wNgx50j/)